# R Shiny- How to Subset Dataframe, Save the Subsetted Dataframe, Print Summary Information?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I'm extremely new to Shiny Apps. So far, what I've aimed to do is have a drag-down menu for the user where they can choose to subset the data frame by the year column (I wish I could have added a no subset option). This was working fine, however, it did not look pretty (it showed all rows, didn't format in a way where it would only show the head and then have multiple pages to the data frame). Then, I tried to get the number of columns and rows to print, and I have been struggling with this. After fixing this, my hope is to get the subsetted data frame to be downloadable by the user. Any advice?

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("World Happiness Report Data"),
    tags$h3("DS 3002, Project One"),
    tags$h4("By Jasmine Dogu (ejd5mm)"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput('year',"Choose a Year",
               choices = sort(data$year, decreasing = TRUE),
               tableOutput("table1")
               ),
        mainPanel( 
                DT::dataTableOutput('contents'),
                verbatimTextOutput('summary'),
                plotOutput('plot')
        )
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to subset data
server <- function(input, output) {
    data <- read.csv("world-happiness-report.csv")
    category <- data$year
    df_subset <- reactive({
        a <- subset(data, category==input$year)
        return(a)
    })
    
    output$table1 <- renderTable(df_subset()) #Note df_subset() was used and not df_subset
   
    output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(df_subset())       
    })
    
    output$summary <- renderPrint({
        summary(df_subset())
    })
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You can use `pageLength = 5` in `datatable` to show only 5 rows per page.

Comment: unfortunately I am not able to run your app, since it is missing a csv file. Have you looked at the [DT extensions page](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html), it shows how to add download buttons